# MongoDB C# Driver: throw exception when querying on ignored property

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the MongoDB C# Driver v2.7.x, but I was wondering given a POCO class, is there anyway to raise warnings when querying on unmapped properties.

For example, I have the following class:

```
public class GroceryList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
}
```

So whenever I store this object, `IsOwner` is not inserted into the database ([see also the ignore member docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/mapping/#ignoring-a-member)). However when I perform `GetCollection<GroceryList>(..).AsQueryable().Where(gl => gl.IsOwner)`, this gets translated into `{$match: {IsOwner: true}}`, thus the element is still used in the query ([see also the MongoDB LINQ docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/linq/)).

Now in this trivial example it's easy to spot the problem; however when there's a few layers of indirection and a function starts returning an `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`, it gets harder. So I would like to prevent the situation where ones could query on any field that's not mapped. Preferably through some convention (`IMemberMapConvention`).

Comment: I don't think that was the intent of `BsonIgnore`, but I do understand your point of view. The real catch of course is because the BSON translation from `IQueryable` is effectively an aggregation pipeline, the general *"design wisdom"* here is consistent across language drivers as *"Aggregation pipelines change document structure, therefore are not bound to class types"*. It's not just a C# thing, but everywhere that even attempts some kind of "class mapping". I have argued in the past that the **initial** `$match` should be considered in the *"class shape"* from the original model.

Comment: My expectation would be that when working with LINQ queries, as long as the query is generic over the class (so excluding projections etc), the only available properties to that query would be the ones visible to the driver. Thus excluding any properties that are excluded from the class map. But I guess there's no such feature. I don't even think it uses custom serializers, otherwise I could just have thrown an exception from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a small test project, I found that `[BsonIgnore]` would do exactly what I expected:

> InvalidOperationException: {document}.IsOwner is not supported.

After some digging I found the problem was caused by how we ignore our members. In order to not have to reference Mongo in our domain layer, we introduced custom attributes that would do the same as Mongo's builtin attributes. However our implementation didn't correctly ignore members, but just disabled serialization for them:

```
  if (mm.MemberInfo.IsDefined(typeof(CustomIgnoreMappingAttribute), true))
  {
-     memberMap.SetShouldSerializeMethod(o => false);
+     classMap.UnmapMember(memberMap.MemberInfo);
  }
```